# Mercurial creating extra files after cloning a repo

Tags: android, version-control, mercurial

I am working on an Android App and the APK file is located in the *out* folder. I am also using Mercurial as version control system and cloned the repo, the clone was successful but Mercurial created two APK files one inside the *bin* directory and another in the root directory of the project.

Why Mercurial created these extra two APK files and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You **have** these two files in repo, clone just show it to you
2. You *didn't see only* these files in original Working Copy, because (not discovered yet) local settings for original workspace **now** ignore these files (after they was commited to repo - see `hg log FILENAME`), but adding to ignore-list doesn't mean "automatically forget and remove from repo"

> how to get rid of them?

- In cloned repo-root create .hgignore, add global pattern for all and any (?) *.apk-file
- `hg forget` both APK (or Forget from CMenu of THG)
- commit changes
- remove files from WorkingCopy